# How to go to fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock, I am not able to go to class that extends SherlockFragment from activity

I need to move from Activity to fragment class

Here is my Activity class

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,MessagesFragment.class);
```

And the Fragment class is like

```
public class MessagesFragment extends SherlockFragment implements
    OnItemClickListener {

// Layout parameters declaration
private PullToRefreshListView lv_messages;
private ImageView iv_no_data;
private LinearLayout ll_bg;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(
            true);
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(
            true);
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(
            R.layout.header);
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#009fe3")));
    TextView txt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.tv_title_header);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
            "georgia.ttf");
    txt.setText("MESSAGES");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_refreshable, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
.
.
.
.
}
```

If I use `switchfragment` method it shows lots of errors in `FragmentChangeActivity`

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (getActivity() == null)
        return;

    if (getActivity() instanceof FragmentChangeActivity) {
        FragmentChangeActivity fca = (FragmentChangeActivity) getActivity();
        fca.switchContent(fragment);

    }
}
```

Comment: No idea what exactly you're asking. ActionbarSherlock supports fragments, and if you go to his github you'll find a load of examples using them.

Comment: I was not able to go from activity to fragment class

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to created a class that extends FragmentActivity and start yourfragment there

```
public class MessagesFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, new MessagesFragment ()).commit();}
    }
}
```

Your fragment constructor.

```
public YourFragment() {
}
```

then from you calling activity, start your fragment activity in the normal way

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this,MessagesFragment.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It works it takes me to another activity. Struggling a lot for this code.

Comment: where shld we call the fragment constructor?

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar in the Fragment file, inside the class, if you are using kotlin you need to use init{...} as constructor

Answer (score 1):

Use `FragmentTransaction` to go to any Fragment you want. If you have several Fragments, this method will switch between them.

Here is direction:

```
public enum FragmentsAvailable {    
HISTORY
 }


public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity
 ...

 private void changeFragment(Fragment newFragment, FragmentsAvailable newFragmentType, boolean withoutAnimation) {


    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


    try {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(newFragmentType.toString(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {

    }

    transaction.addToBackStack(newFragmentType.toString());
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();


}
```

Comment: where to keep this code? in my activity or i should create a class. And here there is no class even to pass it

Comment: You put it into your Activity. i'm sure by key words you can find enough info in google

Comment: Ohh, sorry, add `extends FragmentActivity`. I can send you all my class if you want because its only example

Comment: but my class extends to `GCMBaseIntentService`

Comment: if so, you must create other Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. Because every Fragment was contained in a Activity, So you can just jump to a Activity which contains that Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

A fragment is Attached to an activity, you can Add a fragment or Replace a fragment with FragmentTransition. Note that a fragment need an activity to exist !

You don't go from activity to fragment... But if you are in an activity that contain a fragment you can open a new activity on top of the first.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. We can move from activity to fragment by the code below

Comment: Off course you are right, i'm just giving an advice about the MAIN use of fragments. You should admit that this is not common use. If you take a look at official google best practices, fragments are clearly meant to adapt UI between headset, tablets, and orientation changes... Down voting an answer for that kind of reason is idiotic :/