# How to open Fragment from NavigationDrawer that uses onNagivationItemSelected

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

My MainActivity uses `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` that includes an activity. But somehow it won't open the other fragments that I have on the drawer. I can open the fragments if i delete `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)`. But then I can't open BookingActivity.

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//region Properties
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
ImageButton settings_btn;
//endregion

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ProductDatabase productDb = new ProductDatabase();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    settings_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);
    settings_btn.setOnClickListener(v ->
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class)));

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show());

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_login, R.id.nav_treatments, R.id.nav_product, R.id.nav_about, R.id.nav_contactUs)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); // Fragments work if I remove this line, but not BookingActivity
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_booking) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, BookingActivity.class));
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_product) {
        // What to write here to open ProductFragment? 
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_treatments) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contactUs) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this link [How to go to fragment from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011374/how-to-go-to-fragment-from-activity)

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_booking) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, BookingActivity.class));
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_product) {

    // here you will set intent

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_treatments) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contactUs) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
```